# openmp c sleeping barber

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I'm new to OpenMP, and for learning purposes I'm trying to implement the sleeping barber problem. However I can't get the code too run, as I would like.

This is how I would like the code to run:

```
Creating customer 0
Creating customer 1
Creating customer 2
Creating customer 3
Creating customer 4
Sleeping
Customer: 3 waiting for seats
Customer: 3 ready, waiting for barber
Customer: 1 waiting for seats
Customer: 1 ready, waiting for barber
Customer: 2 waiting for seats
Customer: 2 ready, waiting for barber
Customer: 4 waiting for seats
Customer: 4 ready, waiting for barber
Customer: 0 waiting for seats
Customer: 0 ready, waiting for barber
Barber: waiting for customer
Barber: waiting for seats
Customer: 2 is done. Leaving..
Number of customers hair cutted: 1
Barber: waiting for customer
Barber: waiting for seats
Customer: 1 is done. Leaving..
```

However this is how it actually runs:

```
Creating customer 0
Creating customer 1
Creating customer 2
Creating customer 3
Creating customer 4
Customer: 0 waiting for seats
Customer: 0 ready, waiting for barber
Barber: waiting for customer
Barber: waiting for seats
Customer: 0 is done. Leaving..
Customer: 1 waiting for seats
Customer: 1 ready, waiting for barber
Number of customers hair cutted: 1
Barber: waiting for customer
Barber: waiting for seats
Customer: 1 is done. Leaving..
Customer: 2 waiting for seats
Customer: 2 ready, waiting for barber
Number of customers hair cutted: 2
Barber: waiting for customer
etc..
```

As you can see, it's like only one customer at a time, is waiting for the semaphore and they somehow is waiting for the other customer tasks to complete.

The code:

```
void customer(int threadid)
{
    int hairCutted = 0;
    while (!hairCutted) {
        printf("Customer: %ld waiting for seats\n", (long)threadid);
        sem_wait(&accessWRSeats);
        if (numOfFreeSeats >0) {
            numOfFreeSeats--;
            sem_post(&custReady);
            sem_post(&accessWRSeats);
            printf("Customer: %ld ready, waiting for barber\n", (long)threadid);
            sem_wait(&barberReady);
            hairCutted = 1;
        }
        else {
            sem_post(&accessWRSeats);
            hairCutted = 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Customer: %ld is done. Leaving..\n", (long)threadid);
}


void createCustomers(void)
{
    int i;    

    printf("Random number: %d\n", randNum1);

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single firstprivate(i)
        for (i = 0; i < randNum1; ++i)
        {
            #pragma omp task
            customer(i);
            printf("Creating customer %d\n", i);
        }
    }

    printf("Sleeping\n");
    sleep(60);
    int j;
    printf("Random number: %d\n", randNum2);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single firstprivate(i)
        for (j = 0; j < randNum2; ++j, ++i)
        {
            #pragma omp task
            customer(i);
            printf("Creating customer %d\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, "cutted" isn't a word. It's "cut" :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this piece of code:

```
sem_wait(&accessWRSeats);
if (numOfFreeSeats >0)
{
   ...
}
else
{
  sem_post(&accessWRSeats);
  hairCutted = 1;
}
```

Why does the customer gets a haircut if there are no free seats for him to sit? (Which means the barber shop is full, thus, the barber is busy attending on some other client.)
He should signal `accessWRSeats`, leave and try again some other time...

Comment: Yeah, you are right, actually he's not getting his hair cutted, but it's there to stop the while loop. If there's no seats in the waiting room, the customers should just leave the shop.

Comment: Wouldn't he try again later? You could put him to sleep, so that he loses the CPU. Then he would try again later when he gets the CPU back again.

Comment: This would be equal to the customers are waiting on the street, the barber is not interested having people standing there :)

Comment: Well, I agree with you. But I think I'll need to take a look at the rest of your code to see if I can identify any problem.